# Removing brackets

Tags: c#, regex, string

Consider:

```
string value = "http://url.com/index?foo=[01234]&bar=1";
```

I need to remove the `[`  `]`, brackets.

I tried

```
value = value.Replace("[01234]", "1234");
```

and this didn't work.

Should I look into a regular expression?

**EDIT**

I can't do only `[` or `]` because string can contain more than one, `[` or `]`. I just want `foo = [blah]` to be replaced with `foo = blah`**.

Comment: What didn't work? your code works just fine for me with the sample you have given

Comment: What you described should work, look elsewhere in your code, or show us more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a Regex:

```
var value = "http://url.com/index?foo=[01234]&bar=1"; 
value = Regex.Replace(value, "foo=\\[(.*?)\\]","foo=$1");
```

Answer (score 4):

You could just do -

```
value = value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
```

**EDIT**

Or with a regex (not tested) -

```
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(foo=)\[([0-9A-Za-z]+)\]");
    value = value.Replace(subjectString, "$1$2");
```

Comment: What if there are brackets in other parts of this url that don't need to be replaced?

Comment: i cant do only [ or ] because string can contain more than one. [ or ]. I just want foo=[blah] to be replaced with foo=blah

Answer (score 1):

```
value = value.Replace("[","").Replace("]","");
```

Comment: What if there are brackets in other parts of this url that don't need to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need regex. A simple string replace would do it:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string value = "http://url.com/index?foo=[01234]&bar=1";
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(value);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query["foo"] = query["foo"].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        value = uriBuilder.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

This will ensure that only the brackets of the `foo` parameter will be removed.

Comment: Any performance hit with calling Replace twice, with a new string allocated each time?